# facebook android user getUsername

Tags: android, facebook, session

i'm trying to get ,in my app, the username of user that is connected to facebook working on the active session in that moment. In many post I read that the method getUsername() is deprecated. Really? This is my piece of code:

```
        if(session!=null && session.isOpened()){

        Log.i("LandingActivity", "session not null...");

        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(final GraphUser user, final Response response) {
                if (user != null) {

                    String u=user.getUsername();


                    String url="exist_user.php?mail=".concat(u);
                    lf.ftpControl(url);

                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
```

The error is NullPointerException at line where there is the concat function. Help me! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API, it is no longer possible to get the username or the real ID of the user. See the changelog for more information about changes: Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

I see that you are trying to use the username as email, which is not a good idea and one reason why they removed access to it. The proper way to identify returning users is to store their (app scoped) ID, not their email. And if you really need the email of a user, ask for the email permission and you will get it in the result of `/me`.

Comment: thanks! I really need the email of user. I already asked the permission for mail, but I don't understand what is the meaning of /me and How can I use it to retrieve the mail given the variable user or session. Help me!

Comment: /me is the authorized user, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

Comment: ehm ok,I know that page,but it doesn't me anything about how get the mail in Java for Android...

Comment: as i said, the email is in the result of calling the /me endpoint, if you requested the email permission correctly in the login process.

Comment: also, there is example code for android in that link

Comment: sorry,another answer. How can I get the mail in onCompleted function?

Comment: new Request(
    session,
    "/me",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();

Comment: well...debug it ;) - sorry, but we should not discuss completely different topics in comments. if you got another question, better open a new thread. comments are just for...well, comments ;)

Comment: ok,maybe I have answered my question by myself :) Thanks for all!